# Server Side pagination with sort and search and multiple languages support

Tags: java, localization, pagination, server-side

I'm curious about if is there any best practice, pattern or recommendation for doing server side pagination for a web application that supports multiple languages.

Right now our application supports multiple languages through database translations, so all our entities look like:

```
            ENTITY X TABLE
---------------------------------------------------------------------
idEntity |   code        |    other attributes.... 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 1          entity1.name         ....
 2          entity2.name         ....
```

And then a "translation" table with all the translations:

```
        TRANSLATIONS TABLE
---------------------------------------------------------------------
idTranslation  |   code        |    idLanguage     |   translation
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 1               entity1.name         1                 myEntity_EN
 2               entity1.name         2                 myEntity_FR
```

So far, this works great, but the problem is that we have a webapp which displays data, and we are implementing server side pagination, and all our data tables must be searchable and sortable by all the columns we display, and of course the search and sort must be based on the translations not the code columns.

For now, the path we are following is adding the sort, search and pagination parameters in the query to the DB, and the DB performs the join of the tables, which seems to work, but it still looks a bit harsh... and I'm a bit worried about performance we have lots of translations.

So, is there any recommendation to follow in this (I think) quite common scenario??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing bad about having the DB to sort the text if you have server side pagination, it's just another join in your statement and your DBMS should be able to handle this quickly, as long as your overall statement is done properly.